# Bookshelf.js Registry [Error: The model ... could not be resolved from the registry plugin.]

Tags: node.js, orm, registry, bookshelf.js

I'm trying to use the registry plugin with Bookshelf.js because I think I am encountering a circular dependency, but I am getting nowhere with it.

Before I was getting this error, I was getting an error:

```
[Error: A valid target model must be defined for the category hasMany relation]
```

I have a Category and Tag model, but I keep getting the error

```
[Error: The model Tag could not be resolved from the registry plugin.]
```

My Category model looks like:

```
var knex = require('knex')(config.knex);
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
bookshelf.plugin('registry');

var Category = bookshelf.Model.extend({
tableName: 'category',
tag: function() {
    return this.hasMany('Tag', 'category_id');
}
});
module.exports = bookshelf.model('Category', Category);
```

and my Tag model looks like

```
var knex = require('knex')(config.knex);
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
bookshelf.plugin('registry')

var Tag = bookshelf.Model.extend({
tableName: 'tag',
category: function() {
    return this.belongsTo('Category');
},
events: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Event, 'event_tag');
},
});
module.exports = bookshelf.model('Tag', Tag);
```

I have no idea where I am going wrong, it is so frustrating. Can anyone help please?????

Comment: Apparently, Bookshelf model must be imported somewhere, like in Controller, or resolved some other way to be put in Registry. If the JS interpreter never reach the Model file, then it will never be registered. Also check for model name case sensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

this.hasMany uses table names or Bookshelf Object names. You want to use `'tag'` (table name) or `Tag` (Bookshelf Object name) but not `'Tag'` (not a table name).

So use this :

```
tag: function() {
    return this.hasMany('tag', 'category_id');
}
```

Or this :

```
tag: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Tag, 'category_id');
}
```

You will have the same problem in your `Tag` model :

```
category: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Category); // (or 'category')
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This error also exist when the corresponding model is not registerd into the `registry` object of `Bookshelf`.
A Quick Fix for this to use the below statement explicitly after extending model -

```
bookshelf.resolve = () => DocumentEditionValueModel;
```

It will register this model to the bookshelf registry object.